# posting an array using JQuery .post()

Tags: php, jquery, .post

so I am rather new to the whole .post() experience with jquery.

I have only experience POSTing input values so far. What I want to do is POST an array.

which is a standard array of a list of numbers. The end goal being: performing a query with these values.

Could somebody explain to me very basically how using JQuery .post() I can post my array?

many thanks,

Comment: Is `$student_numbers` a PHP variable? It looks like. Maybe you should post some code of what you already did.

Comment: i've just pre-constructed my array in PHP from a couple of queries.

Comment: with `$.post()` you send data from your client (JavaScript) to your server (PHP). But you already have the variable on your server. What exactly you are trying to do?

Comment: perform my database queries without refreshing the page basically.

Comment: Thats not very clear from your question. I think the answers already given should point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, without going into great detail, the answer on you question is called `JSON`.

The process is easy:

> Backend (PHP) Array **->** encode as JSON
>   string **->** send that JSON string to the
>   browser **->** decode the JSON string as
>   Javascript Array

Comment: but the issue is, its a university server and I was under the impression not all servers have JSON serialization supported, which I have no idea if this does, so I was hoping there was a different solution.

Answer (score 3):

Check [jQuery.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/). There is an example for posting arrays.

**EDITED:** Example is like;

```
$.post("test.php", { 'choices[]': ["Jon", "Susan"] });
```

Comment: ye i looked at this, but my array is already pre-constructed :S

Comment: So replace the `Jon,Susan` part with your array, e.g. `$.post('test.php', { 'choices[]' : your_array_variable_here }`

Comment: ok thanks Marc, Ill give it whirl. Does my array have to involve the delimeter `,` ? if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Check The jQuery Site and the Docs for [jQuery.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)